# Pass data using TabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I know this question has been ask a lot on stack overflow. So I have a TabBarController that has 2 NavigationController, which both NavigationController have a TableViewController. I am using firebase to get a user, saving the user into a variable called currentUser. Now my problem starts here, I want to set the 2nd Navigation/Tableview controller title to the user's name. I know how to pass data using the prepare for segue, however there is no segue in TabBarController.

I've found a solution, not sure if its good or bad. What I did was make the first controller to be the delegate of the tab bar. Then I added tabBarController did select method. Here is the code.

```
class FirstTableVC: UITableViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var currentUser: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    //Code that saves user
    func code() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers![1] {
            let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as? UINavigationController
            let secondTableVC = navController?.topViewController as! SecondTableVC
            secondTableVC.currentUser = currentUser
        }

    }
}

class SecondTableVC: UITableViewController {

    var currentUser: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title =currentUser?.name
    }

}
```

This works but not sure if this is a good way to do. I was wondering if there is a better way or a more efficient way. Thanks :)

Added:
Okay read this [article](http://Hey%20I%20did%20it%20this%20way,%20however%20I'm%20running%20into%20a%20bug.%20I%20read%20this%20article%20it%20has%20a%20section%20about%20passing%20data%20using%20tabController.%20Here%20is%20the%20[link](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/).%20Now%20what%20does%20he%20mean%20by%20the%20state%20of%20the%20app?%20Would%20really%20appreciate%20the%20help) about passing data using tabController. The author says that we should pass data using the state of the app. I am not really sure what he means by this. This is what I though he meant.

Example code:

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var email: String
    static var currentPerson: Person?

    init(name: String, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

Can some please help me clarify . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this solution. Another way would be to have an abstracted class responsible for the user login object (instead of `FirstTableVC` having responsibility) that is accessible from both `FirstTableVC` and `SecondTableVC`

Comment: can you provide sample code. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your FirstTableVC

```
       func code() {
            ...
            ...
            ...

            self.changeTabbarTitle()
        }

        func changeTabbarTitle() {
            if let items = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
                items[1].title = currentUser?.name
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Vincent, read this article it has a section about passing data using tabController. Here is the [link](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/). Now what does he mean by the state of the app? Would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use with delegate protocol

**create NavigationTitle Protocol in FirstViewController**

```
    protocol NavigationTitle{
    func setTitle(name:String)
}

class FirstViewController: UITableViewController,UITabBarControllerDelegate{
    var delegate: NavigationTitle?

func setCurrentUser(){
    delegate.setTitle(name:self.currentUser?.name)
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers![1] {
        let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as? UINavigationController
        let secondTableVC = navController?.topViewController as! SecondTableVC
        self.delegate = secondTableVC.self
    }

}
```

}

**implement protocol in SecondVC**

```
class SecondVC: UITableViewController,NavigationTitle{
func setTitle(name:String){
navigationItem.title = name
}
}
```

Comment: Hey I did it this way, however I'm running into a bug. I read this article it has a section about passing data using tabController. Here is the [link](http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/). Now what does he mean by the state of the app? Would really appreciate the help

Comment: Check the Q&A section of that article, the author explains there what `State` is